# Pasar de Binario a decimal en javascript

Tags: javascript, binario

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo esta línea de código para cambiar de un binario a un decimal y lo que quiero primero es reversar el numero que me pasen y luego aplicar el for para que ejecute la función de multiplicar por 2 y por el exponente pero hay una parte del que no me valida, me puede ayudar por favor, al colocar numero 111 me deberia imprimir 7, y al colocar 10 me imprime 2 (ese si esta bien)

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  sum = 0
  var numReverse = num.split('').reverse().join('')


  for (i = 0; i < numReverse.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + numReverse[i] * 2 ** numReverse.length - 1;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(BinarioADecimal("100"));
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa que hay una parte que no te valida? ¿Qué parte? ¿Qué errores tienes? ¿Qué estás obteniendo y qué deberías obtener?

Comment: el test debe correr asi :

const {
  BinarioADecimal,
  DecimalABinario,
} = require('../homework.js');

describe('BinarioADecimal(num)', function() {
  it('should return 2', function() {
    expect(BinarioADecimal('10')).toBe(2);
  });
  it('should return 7', function() {
    expect(BinarioADecimal('111')).toBe(7);
  });
});

Comment: El código pareciera funcionar bien. Por favor agrega el código a tu pregunta usando el botón de `editar`, no compartas código en los comentarios.

Comment: No es muy claro qué es lo que falla, qué error ves o qué es lo que debería pasar y no pasa. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y explica esto un poco mejor.

Comment: coloco en console.log 111 y debería imprimir 7, pero me imprime 21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La lógica en el código es incorrecta.

Si tomamos el número binario `1011`, esto es equivalente en decimal a:

(De derecha a izquierda)

`1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^3 = 11`

Sin embargo, tu error se encuentra en la potencia a la que elevas el `2`, que siempre es uno menos el tamaño del string.

Por lo que si cambias esa línea de la siguiente manera debería funcionar:

`sum = sum + numReverse[i] * 2 ** i;`

Aunque quería resaltar que no es necesario reversar el string.

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
       sum += +num[i] * 2 ** (num.length - 1 - i);
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(BinarioADecimal("1011"));
```

Comment: muchas gracias Jon

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que estás usando el largo (`numReverse.length - 1`) para definir los exponentes de tu base, utiliza el contador que equivale a la posición de cada dígito, así:

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  sum = 0
  var numReverse = num.split('').reverse().join('')


  for (i = 0; i < numReverse.length; i++) {
   console.log(`${sum} = ${sum}+${numReverse[i]} * 2 ** ${i} `)
    sum = sum + numReverse[i] * 2 ** i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(BinarioADecimal("111"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pasar un binario a decimal con [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), pasándole el número en binario como primer argumento, y luego la base del número, al ser binario sería base 2: `parseInt(numero_binario, 2);`

```js
console.log(parseInt(11001, 2));

// Más ejemplos
const numeros = [ '1', '10', '1100', '1010', '111001101' ];
numeros.forEach(numero => console.log(parseInt(numero, 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Este código convierte de binario a decimal y viceversa

```js
function ConverirBinarioDecimal(nro = undefined, base = undefined) {
  if (nro === undefined || typeof nro === "string")
    return console.info(`datos ${nro} Incorrectos...`);
  if ( typeof base == 'string' || base == undefined)
    return console.info(`datos ${base} Incorrectos...`);
  if (base === 2 || base === 10) {
    let a = nro.toString();
    return base === 2
      ? console.info(parseInt(a, 2) + ` en base 10 `)
      : console.info(nro.toString(2) + ` en  base 2 `);  
  } 
  
  return console.info(`${base} No es base 10 ó 2...`);
}
ConverirBinarioDecimal(100,2); //100, que es base 2--> convertira a base 10
ConverirBinarioDecimal(4,10); //4, que es base 10 --> convertira a base 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function nBinario(numero) {
  //se declara la funcion pasando como parametro los binarios
  let nDecimal = 0; //declaracion de la variable
  const longNbin = numero.length; //para conocer la longitud de los numeros

  //con un for nos damos cuenta de cuantos numeros hay
  for (let i = 0; i < longNbin; i++) {
    let posicion = longNbin - 1 - i; //esta variable sera la que permita
    //recorrer los numeros de de la derecha hasta la izquierda con i y el -1 es para partir desde 0 cero

    //ahora haremos la variable con base exponente
    let baseExponente = 2 ** i; //la base siempre sera 2 y i sera los indices que contenga los numeros binarios
    nDecimal += numero[posicion] * baseExponente; //qui ncimal sumara el resultado de la multiplicacion
  }
  return nDecimal; //retornamos el numero decimal
}
console.log(nBinario('1000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Actualmente el método parseInt() permite tal conversación lo que debes hacer es enviar el numero binario que deseas y la base que en este caso es 2 y esto te retornará el valor en decimal.

```
let n = 100;
let dec = parseInt(n, 2);
console.log(dec);//4
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Algo menos complejo podría ser de la siguiente forma:

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  let acc = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    acc = acc + (num.startsWith("1") ? num[i] * 2 ** i : num[i] * 2 ** i / 2);
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(BinarioADecimal('111')); // 7
console.log(BinarioADecimal('010101')); // 21
console.log(BinarioADecimal('1010110101')); // 693
```